# Guaranteeing that a Cloud Service never loses its VIP

Tags: azure

I have an application with many custom domains and subdomains that is highly dependent on the VIP of my cloud service remaining constant.  I've read the following article:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/jj614593.aspx

Sometimes I'm tired and do stupid things - I'm trying to protect my end users from accidents like misconfigured deployments or accidental clicks (the "delete staging deployment" button is awfully close to the "delete production deployment" button in the azure portal... for instance).

Are there any further steps that can be taken in Azure to "lock down" the VIP, to prevent accidental deletion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this is truly a production site, you may want to shift to something like PowerShell to do your deployments, and automate as much as possible. This lets you avoid the portal completely (which lets you avoid the accidental wrong-button click). Same with Visual Studio: I only recommend portal/VS deployments for dev/test, not for production (basically for the error-prone issues as you mentioned).

Comment: Nice! I've never used PS before - sounds like it's a good time to learn it.  Thanks David.